# Converting an input to UTF-8 with @tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I'm using TensorFlow 2.4.1. I tried to use tf.strings.unicode_decode for decoding a base64 encoded string with @tf.function, but the error occurred, which ValueError: Rank of `input` must be statically known. I checked that tf.strings.unicode_decode works fine without @tf.function. Is there a way to decode a base64 encoded string with @tf.function? I would appreciate your answer.

I loaded a SavedModel and wanted to change `serving_default`. But I got stuck in converting an input to `UTF-8`. This is the code I have tried.

```py
class CustomTransformer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomTransformer, self).__init__()
        self.model = tf.saved_model.load('./models/transformer/1')
  
    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.string)])
    def call(self, input):

        # Error occurred. ValueError: Rank of `input` must be statically known.
        _input_str = tf.strings.unicode_decode(input_data, 'UTF-8')

        return _input_str
```

Here is the error message.

```
ValueError: Rank of `input` must be statically known.
```

Is there an approach to convert an input to `UTF-8` when trying to change `serving_default` from a loaded SavedModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with `tf.strings.unicode_decode`, you need to specify a shape. (see the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/unicode_decode#args)). In that case, because you're working with a Tensor without any dimension (a simple string), just provide an empty tuple as a shape:

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string)])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I tried to convert the UTF-8 decoded output to characters by using chr() and I got TypeError: an integer is required (got type Tensor). Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You might want to ask an other question, with more details.